# Size of data send via NetLink

Tags: c, linux, kernel, netlink

I'm trying to get the size of a chunk of data sent via NetLink (Linux Kernel).
I have tried with `size = nlh->nlmsg_len - NLMSG_HDRLEN`, but that isn't returning the correct size. 
What's the correct way to get the message's data size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you believe `nlh->nlmsg_len - NLMSG_HDRLEN` is not returning the {message size without header} for the message you are looking at? If nlmsg_len contains, for example, the value 16 (that's what NLMSG_HDRLEN should be), then the payload of this message is empty. Your buffer may have more messages in it that want to be read.

As a side note, I recommend you use libmnl for Netlink message parsing and construction.

Comment: In fact, I want to get the size of the chunk of memory that is returned by ```NLMSG_DATA(nlh)``` and I'm almost completely sure the way I'm trying to calc it's size isn't right. About libnl, I'd like to use it but I haven't found a good/simple example yet.

Comment: **What indicator** is there that the size given by `nlh->nlmsg_len - NLMSG_HDRLEN` is possibly *not* right? About libmnl: it's libmnl, not libnl. Examples are in a directory conveniently called `examples`.

Comment: Oh, in fact I was wrong. The way I'm doing it does indeed returns what I'm looking for. It was another part of my code that was buggy. Sorry for wasting your time!